# kubernetes rediness probe failing

Tags: kubernetes

I have set up and installed kubernetes 1.23.0 on Ubuntu 20
I have noticed the following problem

```
Readiness probe failed: Get "https://192.167.230.20:8443/healthz": dial tcp 192.167.230.20:8443: connect: connection refused
```

I can curl this insecurly

```
curl https://192.167.230.20:8443/healthz -k
OK
```

How can i make the pods to behave same way or how do i fix this problem?

Comment: If you issue is resolved based on the below answer; pls upvote/accept so, that it will be useful other community members.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided indicates that the Kubernetes readiness probe is failing because it is unable to establish a connection to the specified address (https://192.167.230.20:8443/healthz) over TCP. This could be caused by a number of issues, such as:

The specified IP address is incorrect or does not match the actual IP address of your Kubernetes cluster.

The specified port (8443) is blocked by a firewall or not configured correctly.

The Kubernetes API server is not running or is not configured correctly.

The kubelet service on the node is not running or not configured correctly.

The network communication between the node and the api-server is not working properly.

To troubleshoot this issue, you may want to check the following:

Verify that the IP address and port specified in the readiness probe are correct and match the actual IP address and port of your Kubernetes cluster.

Check the firewall and make sure that port 8443 is open and not blocked.

Verify that the Kubernetes API server is running and configured correctly.

Check the kubelet service on the node and make sure that it is running and configured correctly.

Check the network communication between the node and the API server.

It is also a good idea to check the logs of the Kubernetes components and the nodes for more information about the issue.

Comment: i can do a `curl` with `-k` which works fine